# возврат значения

Tags: php, функции

Суть вопроса в простом: существует ли function которая возвратит значение переменной если она существует.
в противоположном случае возвратит что-то подобное false/null итд.

```php
isset()
empty()
```

все это не годится, т.к. 
1) `isset()` если переменная не создана возвращает ошибку.
2) `empty()` возвращает true или false, а мне надо переменную.

мне нужно что-то подобное:

```php
<?php

function returnValue($perem)
{
    return empty($perem) ? null : $perem;
}

?>
```

но этот пример function мне не годится. ошибку возвращяет так как не сушествует переменной!

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$ref in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$ref_source in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>41</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$geo in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>44</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$payload in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$keyboard in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>46</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$reply_message in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>48</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$action in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined property: stdClass::$carousel in <b>/storage/ssd2/169/12967169/public_html/groups/index.php</b> on line <b>58</b><br />
```

часть кода с переменными:

```php
        $_message = $vkAnswer->object->message;

        $id            = returnValue($_message->id);            #идентификатор сообщения.
        $date          = returnValue($_message->date);          #время отправки в Unixtime.
        $peer_id       = returnValue($_message->peer_id);       #идентификатор назначения. 
        $from_id       = returnValue($_message->from_id);       #идентификатор отправителя. 
        $text          = returnValue($_message->text);          #текст сообщения.
        $random_id     = returnValue($_message->random_id);     #идентификатор, используемый при отправке сообщения.
        $ref           = returnValue($_message->ref);           #произвольный параметр для работы с <источниками переходов>. 
        $ref_source    = returnValue($_message->ref_source);    #произвольный параметр для работы с <источниками переходов>.
        $attachments   = returnValue($_message->attachments);   #медиавложения сообщения (фотографии, ссылки и т.п.).
        $important     = returnValue($_message->important);     #true, если сообщение помечено как важное. 
        $geo           = returnValue($_message->geo);           #информация о местоположении.
        $payload       = returnValue($_message->payload);       #сервисное поле для сообщений ботам (полезная нагрузка).
        $keyboard      = returnValue($_message->keyboard);      #<объект клавиатуры> для ботов. 
        $fwd_messages  = returnValue($_message->fwd_messages);  #массив пересланных сообщений (если есть).
        $reply_message = returnValue($_message->reply_message); #сообщение, в ответ на которое отправлено текущее.
        $action        = returnValue($_message->action);        #информация о сервисном действии с чатом.

        unset($_message);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$var = 'test';

function returnValue($perem)
{
    return !empty($perem) ?  $perem : null;
}

returnValue($var ?? null);
returnValue($_message ?? null);
```

Если не существует переменной `$message` то вы будете получать ошибку ещё на передаче параметра в функцию для этого следует сделать проверку при вставке аргумента, по сути вам тогда и функция не нужна, достаточно будет написать так:

```
$id = $_message->id ?? null;
```

Comment: а не подскажете как понемать '??'. это типо: if($var) { if($var) {} else { null; }}

Comment: @СлаваНосков Это тернарный оператор, такой вид доступен для использования с 7 версии php. Вот здесь прочтёте подробнее http://php720.com/lesson/19